# add CollectionViewController as subview of another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

How to instantiate `CollectionViewController` inside `ViewController` and set `CollectionViewControllers` view as subview of `ViewController`? There is a catch with FlowLayout, but I can't find a solution.

I need functionality of same `collectionView` in 2 separate `viewControllers`. Because of that I want to create `CollectionViewController`, that I can reuse with different properties, and assign its view to second `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have already tried this as you didn't really put any code example or explain in detail what exactly your issue is but you can add the collectionViewController as a childViewController to your parentViewController.

```
yourCollectionViewController *yourName = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];

//Add view to the container view tower

[self addChildViewController:yourName];
[self.view addSubview:yourName.view];
[yourName didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```